# number of options of ubuntu keeps increasing after every restart.why?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, hp

Have installed Ubuntu along side Windows 8 and also have run boot repair ,but have to press escape and F9 to boot Ubuntu. The number of Ubuntu boot entries keeps increasing after every restart, why?

[image: my screen after starting and pressing F9]

Comment: I also see that ubuntu options reduce to 3 numbers after I have run boot-repair

Comment: It could be a EFI/BIOS  firmware bug.

Answer (score 0):

How often do you restart?

Periodically, Ubuntu will provide an update to the Linux kernel that underlies Ubuntu. Because that's such a core component of the OS, it leaves the option to boot into the previous kernel version, to mitigate against the slim chance that the new kernel version has issues. After a period of multiple months, you might have several older kernel versions available.